# C++ LIFO queue, easy simple example from FIFO to LIFO

Tags: c++, stack, queue, lifo

How can I make this to a LIFO-> last in first out queue?
Is there any easy way to do so?
This is a FIFO-> fifo in first out queue.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    queue<string> q;

    cout << "Pushing one two three four\n";
    q.push("one");
    q.push("two");
    q.push("three");
    q.push("four");

    cout << "Now, retrieve those values in FIFO order.\n";
    while(!q.empty()) {
        cout << "Popping ";
        cout << q.front() << "\n";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `stack<string>` instead of a queue?

Comment: Yepp. Just replace `std::queue` by `std::stack`. Please, note: `std::queue::front()` -> `std::stack::top()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a stack, this is a LIFO

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stack<string> q;

    cout << "Pushing one two three four\n";
    q.push("one");
    q.push("two");
    q.push("three");
    q.push("four");

    cout << "Now, retrieve those values in LIFO order.\n";
    while (!q.empty()) {
        cout << "Popping ";
        cout << q.top() << "\n";
        q.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
Pushing one two three four
Now, retrieve those values in LIFO order.
Popping four
Popping three
Popping two
Popping one
```